# group by issue with extra columns

Tags: c#, linq

I group the result on the customers zipcode. For each zipcode, I want to see the amount of bookings and the amount of equipment that is ordered.

So far my code looks like this:

```
var statistics = from b in db.Bookings
                 from c in db.Customers
                 where b.customerID == c.id
                 group c by c.zipcode into stat
                 select new { 
                              Zipcode = stat.Key, 
                              NumberOfBookings = stat.Count() 
                            };
```

This code groups result into zipcodes and gives me the amount of bookings in each zipcode. How to get the amount of equipment also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `join`s like in SQL, you can (and it's better) use the **navigation properties** from your model:

```
var statistics = 
    from b in db.Bookings
    group b by b.Customer.zipcode into g
    select new
    { 
        Zipcode = g.Key,
        NumberOfBookings = g.Count(),
        NumberOfEquipments = g.SelectMany(b => b.Equipments).Count(),
    };
```

Note that the `g` variable represents a set of bookings with the same zipcode, so [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to get all associated equipments before applying the `Count` operator.

Of course that's not the only way, for instance you can use `Sum` instead:

```
NumberOfEquipments = g.Sum(b => b.Equipments.Count())
```